# JAVA DFS does not print out required line

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

I am programming a DFS problem in java over the n-puzzle problem. I have the following code :

```
public class Dfssolution
{
    public static int cost=0;

    public static String goal;
    public static int n=3;
    public static HashSet<String> closedlist= new HashSet<String>();
    public static boolean solved = false;
    public static String current;
    public static int spc;
    public static String temp;
    public static LinkedHashSet<String> openlist = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    public Dfssolution()
    {    
    }
    public static void main(String args []){
        String start= "103256789";
        goal = "130256789";
        String temp;
        openlist.add(start);
        while (openlist.isEmpty() == false && solved == false){
            current= openlist.iterator().next();
            openlist.remove(current);
            cost++;
            if(current.equals(goal)){
                System.out.println(cost);
                solved=true;
                break;
            }
            else{

                closedlist.add(current);
                if(checkRight(current)==true && openlist.contains(current) == false && closedlist.contains(current) == false){
                    temp= right(current);
                    openlist.add(temp);


                }
                if(checkUp(current)==true && openlist.contains(current) == false && closedlist.contains(current) == false){
                temp= up(current);
                    openlist.add(temp);

                }
                if(checkDown(current)==true && openlist.contains(current) == false && closedlist.contains(current) == false){
                temp= down(current);
                    openlist.add(temp);

                }
                if(checkLeft(current)==true && openlist.contains(current) == false && closedlist.contains(current) == false){
                temp= left(current);
                    openlist.add(temp);

                }

            }
        }
    }

    public static String left(String s){
        String tem = s;
        spc=tem.indexOf("0");

        char [] x = tem.toCharArray();
        char a = x[spc];
        x[spc] = x[spc-1];
        x[spc-1] = a;
        tem= new String(x);
        return tem;


    }
    public static String right(String s){
        String tem = s;
        spc=tem.indexOf("0");

        char [] x = tem.toCharArray();
        char a = x[spc];
        x[spc] = x[spc+1];
        x[spc+1] = a;
        tem= new String(x);
        return tem;


    }
    public static String up(String s){
        String tem = s;
        spc=tem.indexOf("0");

        char [] x = tem.toCharArray();
        char a = x[spc];
        x[spc] = x[spc-n];
        x[spc-n] = a;
        tem= new String(x);
        return tem;


    }
    public static String down(String s){
        String tem = s;
        spc=tem.indexOf("0");

        char [] x = tem.toCharArray();
        char a = x[spc];
        x[spc] = x[spc+n];
        x[spc+n] = a;
        tem= new String(x);
        return tem;

    }
    public static boolean checkUp(String s){
        spc=s.indexOf("0");
        if(spc > n-1){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static boolean checkDown(String s){

        spc=s.indexOf("0");
        if(spc < n*(n-1)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static boolean checkLeft(String s){
        spc=s.indexOf("0");
        if(spc !=0 &&(spc % n) !=0){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static boolean checkRight(String s){
        spc=s.indexOf("0");
        if(spc !=n-1 && spc % n !=n-1){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I am testing it out to see if it will return the number of nodes expanded(known as 'cost') to reach the goal state in the code. I tested it on a simple problem which is

```
103
256
789
```

as the `start` state and

```
130
256
789
```

as the `goal` state
The program does not print out the `cost` (number of nodes expanded) which should be 2.

Note that `n` represents 3 in a 3x3 puzzle problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move statement `closedlist.add(current);` to the end of else block. Otherwise, every condition checks if `closedlist` contains `current` (and it does, you just put it here), and nothing will be put in `openlist`.

After this changes solution is found in 2 steps, but there is another mistake to work on — you're counting `cost` globally, while it should be counted separately for each branch if you want to find minimal amount of moves.

Comment: By branches do you mean just the if and else statements only or including each of the if statements encapsulated by the else staement?

Comment: For example, if the start position is 103256789, and end position is 013256789 (1 move transition), your solution will check previously 130256789 and 153206789, so cost will be equal to 4 at the end, but in actual path to goal node is only 2 nodes.